# python import functions in multiple files from top level folder

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a directory structure that looks like the following;

```
file.py
module1/
    __init__.py
    module1_file1.py
    module1_file2.py
```

Lets say `module1_file1.py` has a function `foo` and `module1_file2.py` has a function `bar`.
I want to be able to import these functions into `file1.py`, but instead of;

```
from module1.module1_file1 import foo
from module1.module1_file2 import bar
```

I want to be able to write;

```
from module1 import foo, bar
```

How do I go about doing this? I suppose I need to write something in the `__init__.py` so that the functions can be accessed directly from `module1`?

I tried adding the following to `__init__.py`

```
from module1_file1 import foo
from module1_file2 import bar
```

But this gave me the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1_file1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `__init__.py`, instead of:

```py
from module1_file1 import foo
from module1_file2 import bar
```

You can use:

```py
from .module1_file1 import foo
from .module1_file2 import bar
```

These import statements become relative. The `"."` allows Python to resolve the current package which is `module1` and this package is already imported and it can able to find it.

Remember that Python will only recognize packages which are in the `sys.path` list. Since you run the `file.py` file, only *its* directory is going to be added to the `sys.path`, so Python can't find `module1_file1` directly. It has to find it through `module1`. One way is to use absolute import (`from module1.module1_file1 import foo`), and the better one is the mentioned relative import.

Comment: It's also good form to mention your `__init__.py` re-exports in `__all__`: `__all__ = ["foo", "bar"]`.